# How do i apply a function to only a specific div in a collection of divs generated by foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, laravel

When i click on SHOW MORE in one of the divs generated, in every div the footer div shows up with options Test1, Test2. I want the function to apply to the div im clicking on only. Help please :(

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)

    <div class="row">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{$article->title}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">{{$article->content}}</div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="more" onclick="showPortals()">
    Show More</div>
    <div class="other_sources">Other Sources:
                        <a href="">Test 1</a>,
                        <a href="">Test 2</a>
                        <span class="less" onclick="hidePortals()">Show Less</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach
    <script>
        function showPortals() {
            $(".other_sources").show();
            $(".more").hide();
        }
        function hidePortals() {
            $(".other_sources").hide();
            $(".more").show();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: but you have your anchor tags in the footer div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the object you’re clicking via `this` object. You can pass it to your function:

```
<div class="more" onclick="showPortals(this)">

<span class="less" onclick="hidePortals(this)">Show Less</span>
```

Once you have the object representing your element (here, it will be div and span respectively), you can wrap it inside `$` to get a jQuery object. Then, you can use `.closest('.panel-footer')` on the jQuery object to get your panel footer, and `.find(selector)` to find relevant objects inside the current panel-footer:

```
    function showPortals(clickedElement) {
        var $panelFooter = $(clickedElement).closest('.panel-footer');
        $panelFooter.find(".other_sources").show();
        $panelFooter.find(".more").hide();
    }
    function hidePortals(clickedElement) {
        var $panelFooter = $(clickedElement).closest('.panel-footer');
        $panelFooter.find(".other_sources").hide();
        $panelFooter.find(".more").show();
    }
```

However, `onclick="hidePortals(this)"` is not a recommended way of doing things because you’re mixing JavaScript with HTML. Instead, it’s recommended that you remove `onclick="..."` handlers and use jQuery’s `.click` handler, like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.more').click(function () {
        var $panelFooter = $(this).closest('.panel-footer');
        $panelFooter.find(".other_sources").show();
        $panelFooter.find(".more").hide();
    });
    $('.less').click(function () {
        var $panelFooter = $(this).closest('.panel-footer');
        $panelFooter.find(".other_sources").hide();
        $panelFooter.find(".more").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you a ton @Dzmitry. I've been struggling with this for a while

Answer (score 2):

Send the current element to the method

```
<div class="more" onclick="showPortals(this)">
<span class="less" onclick="hidePortals(this)">Show Less</span>
```

Use jquery to and hide/show the desired elements

```
function showPortals(element) {
    var $panelFooter = $(element).closest('.panel-footer');
    $panelFooter.find(".other_sources").show();
    $panelFooter.find(".more").hide();
}
function hidePortals(element) {
    var $panelFooter = $(element).closest('.panel-footer');
    $panelFooter.find(".other_sources").hide();
    $panelFooter.find(".more").show();
}
```

Comment: `el` and `element` should have the same name?

Answer (score 1):

Change your selector to reflect each record's id.

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{$article->title}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">{{$article->content}}</div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="more-{{$article->id}}" onclick="showPortals({{$article->id}})">
    Show More</div>
            <div class="other_sources-{{$article->id}}">Other Sources:
                        <a href="">Test 1</a>,
                        <a href="">Test 2</a>
                        <span class="less" onclick="hidePortals()">Show Less</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
    <script>
        function showPortals(id) {
            $(".other_sources-"+id).show();
            $(".more-"+id).hide();
        }
        function hidePortals() {
            $(".other_sources").hide();
            $(".more").show();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You should probably use a id rather than class if they are specific to the one article

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder I'm thinking about erasing because your answer is a lot better.

Comment: Your solution is better in a way because my solution would stop working if the elements order is changed

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event to every div:

One way:

```
$( document ).on( "click", 'div', doSomething);
```

But if you are trying on an specific id, you may change your selector.